# Is this wsdl fragment illegal?

Tags: wsdl

I'm scratching my head.  This WSDL is generated by CXF.  It liked the input WSDL and schema files but SOAPUI is complaining when I try to create a test project. The whole wsdl is too long but here is the part that matches up with the error messages:

```
<xs:complexType name="RelatedResourcesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RelatedResource">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:CompoundResourceIdentifierType">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="link">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                    <xs:attribute ref="ns3:type" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                    <xs:attribute ref="ns4:href" use="required" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                    <xs:attribute ref="ns5:role" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                    <xs:attribute ref="ns6:title" xmlns:ns6="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                    <xs:attribute ref="ns7:label" xmlns:ns7="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
        ...


...
```

Error: Could not find attribute 'type@http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' Do you mean to refer to the attribute named type@http://dws.sec?

Error: attribute 'href@http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' not found

Error: Could not find attribute 'role@http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' Do you mean to refer to the attribute named role@http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope?

Error: Could not find attribute 'title@http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' Do you mean to refer to the attribute named title@http://metadata.esd.com/?

Error: Could not find attribute 'label@http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' Do you mean to refer to the attribute named title@http://metadata.esd.com/?

So these should all be coming from the xlink definition and I'm not sure why it's not seeing it.  Any thoughts?  or suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: Have you included an include for the xlink schema?

Comment: I see your point.  But there isn't any include as this a generated WSDL.  It's supposed to be "everything you need in one file."  Clearly something is 'off' in the generation.  XmlSpy makes a similar complaint,  It highlights ns3:type and says "ns3:type must refer to an existing attribute".  The definitions should be in here and, for some reason, they are not.

Comment: Your generator tool is broken. It needs an include. The tool is assuming that the consumer will assume the same thing the tool assumed. I've seen this with earlier versions of Java web services, where the WSDL assumed the consumer knew what a `HashMap` was, for instance.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you.  Emboldened by your response, I tried repeating the SoapUi experiment using the original WSDL and schema files. SoapUi was completely happy.  I will attempt to configure CXF to show the original WSDL files.  If I'm successful, I'll post the steps back here.

Answer (score 2):

I had success making changes that allowed Visual Studio 2008 to retrieve the WSDL from the server and to generate code.  The steps were

1) Configure CXF to display the original WSDL files instead of its generated version 
2) Change imported schemas to be inline in the WSDL until Visual Studio is happy

Details:

1) In the CXF configuration file add the wsdlLocation attribute

```
<jaxws:endpoint xmlnse="urn:discovery.services.sec.com"
    id="DiscoveryImpl"
    endpointName="e:discovery"
    serviceName="e:DiscoveryService"
    address="discovery"
    implementor=com.sec.services.discovery.DiscoveryImpl"
    wsdlLocation="WEB-INF\discovery.wsdl
>
```

There are several ways to specify the WSDL location.  Google Code Search was helpful.

2) The original WSDL started off
        
        
            
               
                    
                        ...

Removing the import above, the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions ...>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema ..> <!-- Discovery.xsd contents here -->
                ...
        </xsd:schema>   
    </xsd:types>
        <xsd:schema ..>
            <!-- import of Discovery.xsd removed from here -->
                ...
        </xsd:schema>   
    </xsd:types>
    <wsdl:message ...>
```

I hope this saves some else a little bit of time.

Comment: I'm not sure why the original WSDL got swallowed up but hopefully the change is clear in the bottom snippet.